# How can I read the file data from an ASP.NET web API post request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently I have a "Post" action in my web API controller. I first attempted having a `byte[]` as the only argument, hoping it would "just work". Unfortunately, it did not and it complained about formatting and conversion for `form-data`.

Now I have attempted to read the file content with `this.Request.Content`, which others seem to have had success with. Unfortunately this is including more than I really want: The content disposition, the file name, the content type, and some kind of webkit form boundary. I assume it is all of the request content.

What is the right way to do this? I have found lots of answers for ASP .NET with the FileUpload control and many articles on how to upload to a .NET web API expecting a file via `POST`.

Some articles mention `Request.Files` but it is not part of the `HttpRequestMessage` class.

Comment: Check this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about multipart form data, you should have a look at our official documentation:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't rank high in Google! I searched for "read file content asp.net web api post data" and it wasn't even on the first page. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Youssef please do you think you could help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235617/asp-net-web-api-what-problems-could-arise-if-i-use-post-instead-of-put-and-del/24235652#24235652

Comment: The link is broken